# Databinding build error , android-sunflower sample

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I want to try Android JetPack (Navigation Component Framework).I downloaded Android Studio 3.3 Canary 2 for this and copied the application from github(https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower). But I get an error during build.

Project Gradle =

```
buildscript {
// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 28

    // App dependencies
    constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.0.1'
    glideVersion = '4.4.0'
    gradleVersion = '3.3.0-alpha02'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.2'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    lifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
    navigationVersion = '1.0.0-alpha02'
    kotlinVersion = '1.2.50'
    ktlintVersion = '0.24.0'
    ktxVersion = '0.3'
    roomVersion = '1.1.1'
    runnerVersion = '1.0.1'
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0-alpha3'
    workVersion = '1.0.0-alpha04'
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradleVersion"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
}
```

App Gradle =

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
dataBinding {
 enabled = true
}
defaultConfig {
 applicationId "com.google.samples.apps.sunflower"
 minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
 targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
 testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 versionCode 1
 versionName "0.1.3"
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
 javaCompileOptions {
  annotationProcessorOptions {
    arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
        "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
   }
   }
 }
 buildTypes {
   release {
    minifyEnabled false
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
  }
 compileOptions {
 sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  kapt { generateStubs = true } 
  }

 dependencies {

 kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
 kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$rootProject.glideVersion"

implementation 
"android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment- 
ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui- 
ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
implementation 
"android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime- 
ktx:$rootProject.workVersion"
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$rootProject.ktxVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat- 
v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support- 
v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview- 
v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
layout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation 
"com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation 
"com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk8:$rootProject.kotlinVersion"

// Testing dependencies
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
contrib:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
}
```

Error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sminT.png)

Thank you

Comment: I tried to run in the stable version of android studio, and it compiled perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Android JetPack (Navigation Component Framework) on Android 3.2 Canary 14 or higher. As tell us here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing?utm_source=android-studio&utm_medium=studio-assistant

you can try with Android Studio 3.2 Beta 2.

Althought I am not reproducing the issue by just downloading the project and running it on 3.3 Canary 2.

do you change something apart of the gradle version that is needed?

Greetings.